# phpMyAdmin SSL configuration

Tags: apache, ssl, phpmyadmin

I have 2 MySQL users, a regular 'tommy' and a control user 'tommy_ctl'
The Apache httpd 2.4.7 runs on 9090 for http and 9080 for https

phpMyAdmin (v4.1.6) config.inc.php file has user/password for 'tommy_ctl'
I am logging into phpMyAdmin home page as 'tommy'

Now
a) In config.inc.php
with

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;  
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = false;
```

I can logon to

```
http://linuxboxA:9090/phpMyAdmin/index.php  
https://linuxboxA:9080/phpMyAdmin/index.php
```

b) When I set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
```

why does

```
https://linuxboxA:9080/phpMyAdmin/index.php
```

on logon give the error ?:

```
 #1043 Cannot log in to the MySQL server  
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed
```

Is this SSL option not for communication over Apache?

c) When i set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;  
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;
```

The https 9080 url takes many many seconds to open

```
https://lnappd201.hphc.org:9080/phpMyAdmin/index.php
```

and on logon becomes

```
https://lnappd201.hphc.org/phpMyAdmin/index.php?token=23771cb3b3851979903c6eb233465fd8
```

Note, that there's no port# in the redirected url

Also,

```
http://lnappd201.hphc.org:9090/phpMyAdmin/index.php
```

becomes immediately (without any logon)

```
https://lnappd201.hphc.org/phpMyAdmin/?SID
```

When 'ForceSSL' is set, phpMyAdmin apparently doesn't know that apache SSL is on port 9080,
so how does the ForceSSL option work?

My intention is, even if Apache is running on both the ports, I want phpMyAdmin to use SSL and   ForceSSL (to Apache SSL)

Answer (score 2):

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl']` is for communication between the [web server and MySQL server](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl).

`$cfg['ForceSSL']` should force your [web browser connection to phpMyAdmin to be over HTTPS](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_ForceSSL).

As noted in the documentation for ForceSSL, enabling it in certain configurations (I suspect a nonstandard https port may apply) will require you to set [`$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_PmaAbsoluteUri) so phpMyAdmin knows what port to use.

Hope that helps!

Comment: As stated in the documentation of `$cfg['ForceSSL']` , `Deprecated since version 4.6.0: This setting is no longer available since phpMyAdmin 4.6.0. Please adjust your webserver instead.`

Comment: True, but this question and answer that you've responded to is nearly six years old and the original poster clearly specified using phpMyAdmin version 4.1.6. If you're having trouble with this, I think posting a new question with more details about your specific problem is going to get you better results than downvoting my quite old answer.

Comment: I just wanted to let people coming here know that this solution no longer works for newer versions; because this question is on the first page of google for related searches.

Comment: Commenting again since this was recently revisited by another commenter...There's no good way to clean up this answer for phpMyAdmin after 4.6.0; the solution is to properly configure the webserver. Prior to 4.6.0, phpMyAdmin forced the connection to behave particular ways (especially useful with a proxy or SSL server or other solution that re-wrapped the initial response). Since then, phpMyAdmin does not attempt to force the webserver to act in a specific way, so the conditions presented by the problem shouldn't exist. If there's a similar problem since 4.6.0, it should be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reconfiguring the web server, you can re-wash everything putting your phpmyadmin behind a load balancer, e.g. nginx which will take care (upon SSL configuration) to proxy your http phpmyadmin into an https service.